# How to retrieve selected row from html table using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

I am creating a web app using express and node.js. I have a table that is generated using ejs with data from a database. Below is the code that creates the table:

```
<form action="/user-orders" method="POST">
                        <table id="order-history">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Date of Order</th>
                                    <th>Order ID</th>
                                    <th>Order Total</th>
                                    <th>Order Status</th>
                                    <th>Tracking Info</th>
                                    <th>Order Details</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <% orders.forEach(function(order){ %>
                                <tr>
                                    <td name="date"><%= order.date%></td>>
                                    <td name="id"><%= order.id%></td>
                                    <td name="cost"> &dollar;<%= order.cost.toFixed(2) %></td>
                                    <td name="status"><%= order.status%></td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" class="profile-edit-btn"
                                            style="color:#0062cc; background:rgb(29, 29, 29); width:100%"
                                            name="viewTracking" value="View" id="viewTracking">
                                    </td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" class="profile-edit-btn"
                                            style="color:#0062cc; background:rgb(29, 29, 29); width:100%"
                                            name="viewOrder" value="View" id="viewOrder">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <% }) %>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

Which displays this:
[image]

What I was wondering is how I can get the values from the selected row when I click one of the buttons.

i.e: clicking view in row 1 would return:

```
{
    date: Fri Sep 17 2021 00: 00: 00 GMT + 1200(New Zealand Standard Time),
    id: 2,
    cost: $5556.00,
    status: 'Pending',
}
```

I tried the two code snippets below, but they both return undefined:

```
app.post('/user-orders', function (req, res) {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
        if (body.length > 1e6)
            req.connection.destroy();
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        var result = qs.parse(body);
        console.log(result);
    });
})

app.post('/user-orders', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
})
```

Comment: Duplicate element ids, such as the view details inputs and view tracking inputs have is invalid HTML and should be gotten rid of. As it stands there is no selection mechanism client-side to tell the server what row was clicked. Are you trying to not have JavaScript on the front end? If so you probably need a radio button to select a row and only have a single pair of view buttons. If you do intend an intelligent front-end, please share the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Since your whole `<table>` contains only *one* `<form>`, the contents of *all* `<tr>` rows will be submitted to `/user-orders` no matter which submit button is clicked, and the field names will be duplicate as already pointed out.

Better have one `<form>` per `<tr>` row, then only the contents of that row will be submitted.

Note that an HTML form will submit the data in urlencoded format, like

```
date=2021-09-17&id=2&cost=$5556.00&status=Pending&viewTracking=View
```

Will `qs.parse` be able to parse this format?